# React DOM gets rendered before the ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs, fusioncharts

Hi I am new to react and trying to build a react component that should display charts and I am using the fusion charts to do so. And I need to fetch the data dynamically through an API to feed it to the chart. But the chart renders without the data and the ajax request is initiated only after the chart is loaded. Also I want to know how to re-render the ReactDOM once the data is available

My code snippet:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery'
import FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
import ReactFC from 'react-fusioncharts';
import chart from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts';
class MyApp extends React.Component {
      render() {
          var chartData;
                $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'someurl',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {    
                chartData =data;
                alert(chartData);
 }
            });

          var chartConfigs = {
    type: "Column2D",
    className: "fc-column2d", // ReactJS attribute-name for DOM classes
    dataFormat: "JSON",
    dataSource: {
        chart:{},
        data: chartData
    }
};  
        return (
            <div>< ReactFC {...chartConfigs }/></div>  

        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyApp />,
    document.getElementById('chart-container')
);
```

Comment: don't add ajax code in render... use lifecycle methods - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

this belongs in `componentWillMount(){}` and you should render some placeholder stuff like 'loading' - then change state when data arrives.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff Depends-didMount is the official recommendation unless you're using a workaround for server-side rendering.

Comment: Probably true, but it allows you to do other composition like setting state before render so I prefer `willMount / willUnmount`. My criteria is: if the operation does not require touching / working with the DOM, do it eagerly / early before render, else, wait for the mount. Though, truth be told, it has been a while since I've written a UI component with domain knowledge of a backend that does not just get its data as props. This is just a quick hack to get things working before you factor in a model like redux or mobx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

As the pointer `this` here is tricky. So before the `ajax` call you need something to point to "current" object by assigning `that = this`.

Another way to do is bind the `ajax` function.

`$.ajax({...}).bind(this)`

---

I would store your `chartData` in `state`. Then execute the ajax in `componentWillMount` as @Dimitar Christoff has stated. When ajax call is finished, use `setState` to trigger `render`.

```html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery'
import FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
import ReactFC from 'react-fusioncharts';
import chart from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts';
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chartData: null; // OR whatever type to fit your data
    }
  }
  
  componentWillMount() {
    let that = this
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'someurl',
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        that.setState({chartData: data});
      }
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    let chartConfigs = {
      type: "Column2D",
      className: "fc-column2d", // ReactJS attribute-name for DOM classes
      dataFormat: "JSON",
      dataSource: {
          chart:{},
          data: chartData
      }
    };  
    
    return (
      <div><ReactFC {...chartConfigs }/></div>  
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyApp />,
    document.getElementById('chart-container')
);
```

Comment: <3 the hero we need

Comment: I tried something similar to this but in the componentDidMount() earlier but that did not help me. When I try executing the code I get error stating this.setState is not a function and my chart is not rendering. Am I missing something? This react is entirely new to me and I am just trying to learning

Comment: @Firice Nguyen That did help in getting rid of the this.setState error. But still I am facing some issue. What should be given ( data: chartData) here. Is it something like (data: this.state.chartData)

Comment: @JDP: yeah, you are right. It should be `data: this.state.chartData` inside `render`. What is your issue now ?

Comment: I get some irrelevant issue Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. I could not understand where this is occurring and why the chart is not rendering

Comment: Then problem now is your `ReactFC` component. Do the `console.log(data)` return your expected data?

Comment: @Firice Nguyen Yes console.log(data) returns the expected result. Trying to figure out what the issue is. Will update once I has resolved it. Thanks for the help !!!

Comment: @Firice Nguyen I am unable to resolve the length undefined issue.This seems to be something to do with the fusion charts. Thanks for helping me. I am accepting your answer

Comment: A usual dirty way for `length undefined` is to edit at every place that call `some_var.length` to `(some_var || []).length`. You can try within your component. Good luck !

Comment: @Firice Nguyen My issue got resolved. Actually I was converting the data as  that.setState({chartData: JSON.stringify(data)}) since I thought the data was an object after removing the JSON.stringify it got resolved